# how to discard checkbox value and show value get from database if bootstrap modal box click on no button

Tags: jquery

how to show checkbox value get from the database? when I click on checkbox then open a bootstrap modal box. then I click Yes button to store the checkbox value in a database. but if I click on No Button so not reset checkbox real value get from the database.
This is my bootstrap modal box:-

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
            <h4 class="title">Confirm Message</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="formdata" method="post" action="" name="bootslider">
                <div class="modalform">
                    <h3 class="text-center" id="text"></h3>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="enable_disable" id="is_active">
                    <button type="button" onclick="active_deactive()" data-dismiss="modal" name="status" data-toggle="enable_disable" id="active" class="success-btn"><i class="fa-check"></i><i class="fa-spinner" style="display: none;"></i>Yes
                    </button>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="setting_no" class="danger-btn" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>No</a>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is my modal box value set script:-

```
<script>
$('input[name="is_active"]'). change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        $("#is_active").val(1);
        $('#enable_disable').modal('toggle');
        $('#text').html('Are you sure for active');
        //alert("Checkbox is checked.");
    }
    else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        $("#is_active").val(0);
        $('#enable_disable').modal('toggle');
        $('#text').html('Are you sure for deactive');
    }
});
```

And THis is my No button script for reset value of checkbox button:-

```
<script>
$("#setting_no").on("click", function () {
    $('#enb').prop("checked", function(){ 

        return this.name;
    });
});
```

Then how to i show checkbox real value if click on No button without refresh page.

Comment: store the database value into one variable and reset it when clicked on no

Comment: yes, I stored a value in a single variable. and use reset but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value into variable and use it later
Please check comments

```js
   // assign the value from the database you got
var initialValue = false;
$().ready(function() {

    $('#checkbox').change(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
})

$("#no").click(function() {
    //reset the checkbox value
    $('#checkbox').prop('checked', initialValue);

});

$("#yes").click(function() {
   //save the checkbox value into database
    alert('save ' + $('#checkbox').is(":checked") + ' into database');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="no" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <button id="yes" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working your code. and I am using appEnableDisableSetting() function to save checkbox value a value. I am using No button only for show real value got from a database.

Comment: @vicky793 first try to understand the code I put, then if you still not able to do it, add your function code and create some demo